# I have an issue to find a routing service for each user in here map

Tags: javascript, maps, here-maps-rest

i'm using here map to find a Route of multiple users and destination. 
I type new york in search bar and hit search button, let suppose api return array of ten users. Now i want to get routing service for each users.

```
for(var i=0; i< aws_data.length; i++)
{

    aws_possition = 
    {
        lat: aws_data[i].lat,
        lng: aws_data[i].lng
    };
    lat2 = aws_possition.lat;
    lng2 = aws_possition.lng;

    var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
        parameters = {
                waypoint0: lat1+","+lng1,
                waypoint1: lat2+","+lng2,
                mode: 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
                departure: 'now'
        };
}
```

Now when i run this code platform.getRoutingService is run 10 times before giving me result of each user.
 here is my complete for loop code.

```
   for(var i=0; i< aws_data.length; i++)
{

    aws_possition = 
    {
        lat: aws_data[i].lat,
        lng: aws_data[i].lng
    };
    lat2 = aws_possition.lat;
    lng2 = aws_possition.lng;

    var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
        parameters = {
                waypoint0: lat1+","+lng1,
                waypoint1: lat2+","+lng2,
                mode: 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
                departure: 'now'
        };
        console.log(parameters);
        //debugger;
    router.calculateRoute(parameters,
            function (result) {

            }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Farrakh and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are using [this API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/routing.html) then you can map your data to promises (note that promises need to be polifilled for IE and (very) old browsers)

```
const router = platform.getRoutingService(),
  waypoint1 = aws_possition.lat + ',' + aws_possition.lng,
  mode = 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
  departure = 'now';
Promise.all(
  aws_data.map(
    ({ lat, lng, id }) =>
      console.log(`processing ${id}`) ||
      new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        router.calculateRoute(
          {
            waypoint0: lat + ',' + lng,
            waypoint1,
            mode,
            departure,
          },
          (result)=>resolve([id,result]),
          reject,
        ),
      ),
  ),
).then(
  (results) => console.log('I have results:', results),
  (error) => console.log('something went wrong:', error),
);
```

Comment: No its not working as i want and in results it disturb the sequence also. 
this is my array data
    {lat: 44.9887974188151, lng: -122.972739162038, id: "+15108629326", updatedDateInMillis: 1542083089077}
I have to show the result against this id but even in result it changes the original latitude and longitude but in different ways.

Comment: The only way i left is to compare latitude and longitude but because of changing i'm unable to do this. Please help me

Comment: @FarrukhSultan I have added the id to the result. If you don't get any errors then it should log the results, what is wrong with the results?

Comment: I'm getting output in repeated data 
and these repeated data i'm getting 10 times
I have results: (10) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]

Comment: @FarrukhSultan You can see the values of the array when you click on it. It should have a different id and route result for each value. if the route result is the same for each one then you can try `platform.getRoutingService().calculateRoute(` instead of `router.calculateRoute(`

Comment: Bro still same issue i have